# How fair is comparing a pair of long wires with a capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, wiring

Long ago I was reading an explanation why twisted pair is batter than just a pair of wires. That text was discussing long distances - miles or dozens of miles. It said that two wires in parallel acted like a capacitor, so whenever the sender wanted to send a pulse and raised the voltage that long "capacitor" would take some time to charge and so the receiver would see slowly rising voltage instead of a pulse and when the pulse ended at the sender side by quickly lowering voltage the "capacitor" would continue discharging and so the receiver would see slow decrease in voltage. So transmitting short pulses was just impossible - pulses had so be impractically long.

How fair is such explanation and comparing a long pair of wires with a capacitor?

Comment: Two wires in parallel **are** a capacitor.

Comment: To be fair, two wires in parallel are really a *transmission line*

Comment: Everything has capacitance, so everything *is* a capacitor. The question is, is this aspect of the object in question a dominant, defining, or significant characteristic compared to its other characteristics when considering a particular behavior. Olin correctly describes why capacitance is only a part of the observed behavior of the wire pair.

Comment: Two wires in parallel are *also* an antenna.

Answer (score 8):

Summarised Solution:

- Your text has some correctness to what it says but is misleading.
- Both a spaced pair of wires and a twisted pair will round pulses. It is likely that a spaced pair of parallel wires will allow **faster** pulse transmission easier BUT the reason for twisting pairs is largely unrelated to data speed. Wires are twisted to reduce interference. In a twisted pair the distance to a radiating noise source is equal for both wires - there is no net coupling area to couple to the noise source and any induced noise signals cancel. [Simplified answer].

But

- A pair of wires looks like a capacitor.
- The effect of the capacitance (and other factors) is to limit the "sharpness" of the pulse which can be transmitted

Because (at least)

- A capacitor CANNOT have its voltage instantaneously changed.

Plus

- A pair of wires has inductance and resistance as well.

But

- In many practical cases, while the shape of the pulse is affected by the wire characteristics, you can still get some very fast very square looking pulses transmitted using adequate technical magic. 1 gigabit per second LANs are a good existence proof of fast pulse transmission. A circuit that severely rounds a 1 GB/s pulse stream  will pass  a squarish looking 100 mbps pulse stream and a VERY square looking 10 mbps pulse stream.

---

A pair of wire acts as a capacitor (capacitance C), plus has an inductance L and a resistance R: thus it is an RCL circuit.

These properties (C, R, L) are all "distributed".
 Effectively a pair of wires may be modelled as an infinite series of "sections" with each section comprising a series inductor and a series resistor in each "leg" plus a capacitor between the two "legs". When a pair of wires is used to transmit signals in an environment where the pair's RCL  characteristics have a significant effect o the signal it is known as a "transmission line".

If you just "lump" all the inductance and all the resistance and all the capacitance together the results differs from when they are distributed.

A transmission line will tend to have increasing attenuation with frequency.
 This means that pulse edges tend to get rounded as the squareness of the edges depends on high frequency components.

Answer (score 5):

What you are missing is that a long pair of wires (doesn't matter if they are twisted or not for this purpose) is not just a distributed capacitor, but also a distributed inductor and resistor.  These together make what is called a *transmission line*.

I'm not going to get into the considerable theory and math behind transmission lines, but as quick overview a transmission line has several important characteristics:

It acts as a *delay* as apposed to a capacitor that has to charge up.

Usually has a fairly sharp upper frequency cutoff.

Has a *characteristic impedance*.  This may seem unintuitive at first, but if you had a long transmission line with everything starting out in steady state at 0V and you put a fixed voltage step at one end, the line would draw a fixed current at that end for at least as long as it takes the signal to propagate to the end of the transmission line and back.

Since a fixed voltage is applied and that causes the line to draw a fixed current, the line looks like a resistor, at least until the signal propagates to the other end and back.  This is called the *characteristic impedance* of the line, and will be listed for any cable intended to be used this way.  Common twisted pair may be around 120 Ω or so.  Coax cables are commonly available in 50 Ω and 75 Ω varieties.

Now imagine the same long transmission line we put a voltage step in at one end, but this time a resistor matching the characteristic impedance was connected to the other end.  To the transmission line, the terminating resistor looks just like a infinitely long piece of more transmission line.  Back at the driving end, the transmission line looks like it has the characteristic impedance forever, since there is no difference between a resistor at the other end and more of the same transmission line.

So up to some upper frequency limit, the transmission line acts more like a delay line.  When you put a voltage step in one end, it will propagate relatively unchanged to the other end.  The speed of propagation is slower than the speed of light in vaccuum, and is related to the characteritic impedance, but like I said, I'm not getting into the details and the math.

Comment: It's important to note that when delay lines include "significant" resistance the delay and attenuation will vary with frequency.  Although the time required for a pulse to travel down a delay line will in some sense increase linearly with the length of the line, the time required for a step change to reach a certain fraction of its original amplitude will increase as the square of the length of the line.

Comment: Actually the speed of propagation depends mostly on the medium the electromagnetic wave travels through, which for twisted pair is mostly the insulating material between the wires, and to a small part the air surrounding it. For common twisted pair in Ethernet cables (which are descendants of telephone cables) the insulation is polyethylene, and the speed is about 2/3 of the speed of light (20cm/ns).

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day a capacitor is merely two metal plates separated from each other by some insulating layer.  A pair of wires, side by side, is simply two very very long, very very thin, plates, separated by an insulating layer.  A capacitor.

The wire itself has a resistance too.  Resistance in series, and capacitance to ground, that's your basic passive low-pass filter.

The main benefit from twisted-pair is when you have a differential signal - one polarity in each wire of the pair.  Induced noise is induced pretty much identically in each wire of the twist, and then canceled out by subtracting the two polarity signals at the receiver.